# Get all discussions where a discussion has at least two active participants?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple one-on-one chat program, and I'd like to find out the discussions where both participants have sent at least one message. How would I form such a query?

The tables are like this (simplified):

```
Table USER
- id
- username

Table DISCUSSION
- id

Table MESSAGE
- id
- user_id (the user who sent the message)
- discussion_id (the discussion this message belongs to)
```

So essentially, I need to check that there's at least two `MESSAGE` rows that have the same `discussion_id` but `different user_id`'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT discussion_id FROM message
  GROUP BY discussion_id 
  HAVING count(user_id) > 1
```

should do it.

If your discussion table have more columns e.g. a subject of debate, you can join it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Such an elegant solution. I thought it would be a mess of subqueries and such. :)